# What are the dragonflies used for in Little Balancing?

Tags: little-balancing

My question is about this game for little people: http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/134434/little-balancing

The set is nice quality, it's fun and quick to play, and very collaborative without much strategy.  Along with the stems, lilies and frogs, the set includes a dozen dragonfly tokens.  But nowhere in the (small) rulebook or online can I find reference to how the dragonflies are used in the game.

Any ideas?  What do you do with your dragonflies?

Comment: Point trackers?

Comment: Sometimes you can get a hint from how they are named in the rules. Check the list of the box's contents.

Comment: The contents and rules that came with the game make no mention of the dragonflies. But I just found a newer set of English rules in the (cute but very difficult to navigate) Djaco website, which says they are point counters.

Comment: @Jeff Snider - That website is insane(I gave up)! If you can post a direct link to the English rules as an answer, that would be great.

Comment: @ire_and_curses, And you call yourself a gamer? Shame on you! ;) After the loading to 100%, you gotta through another wait to 100% which appear over the dude's head. Then pick a language from the road sign that pops up, then pick "Rules" from the menu that appears on the bottom. Easy! ;)

Comment: @Ikegami - Indeed, I lack tenacity. Oh, how obvious! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rules](http://www.djeco.com/medias/rule/GB/DJ08554_GB.pdf) on the publisher's site lists them as follows in the box's contents:

> 15 “point won” counters

The only other mention of them in the rules follows:

> When all the elements have been placed on the platform, the game is won. Each player thus takes a “point won”.

Comment: I'd add the comment that there is a picture of the dragonfly counters with "15x" next to it, before the text you quote.  Here's the deep link, for those without the patience to navigate the cute website: http://www.djeco.com/medias/rule/GB/DJ08554_GB.pdf

Comment: I already provided that link in my answer. I'm not sure how to mention the pictures or see the point of it.